# Get file type after sending the file from WebRTC

Tags: javascript, download, webrtc, filereader

I am using WebRTC to get two clients communicated using peer.js

```
var peer = new Peer(
{
    key: "XXX",
    config: {"XXX": [{ url: "XXXXXXX" }]}
});
```

My main aim is to send file from one client to another. For that I am using following code:

```
$("#box").on("drop", function(e)
{
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    connection.send(file);
});
```

On the receiving end I am using below code:

```
conn.on("data", function(data)
{
    if (data.constructor === ArrayBuffer)
    {
        var dataView = new Uint8Array(data);
        var dataBlob = new Blob([dataView]);
        var reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(dataBlob); 

        console.log(reader);
    }
}
```

Now my problem is I want to get the file type so that I can save it in the proper format. I am using download.js to save the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get the type from the raw data except there is some file type/hint embedded in the data (e.g. ZIP, PDF). You should create you own protocol to send the filename as well.

What I did is to use the channel's protocol property to set the filename with extension to transfer these type of metadata information.

Note that a few weeks ago sending blobs wasn't fully supported in Chrome (at least in one of my example applications).